# SQL Query Result set change the Column Value Group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a sql query result as like below

[image]

And i need the output like

[image]

How do we achieve this. Trying to find the solution for more than half a day.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain the logic.  And tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select userid, name, coursename, applicationtype,
       (case when min(classdate) = max(classdate) then min(classdate)
             else min(classdate) || ' - ' || max(classdate)
        end) as classdate
from t
group by userid, name, coursename, applicationtype;
```

This uses the standard operator, `||` for string concatenation.  Some databases have their own methods for implementing this.

Comment: Thanks, Its works as expected .. But am using SQL , so Instead of || , we use + symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `GROUP BY`, as in:

```
select
  userid, name, coursename, applicationtype,
  min(classdate),
  max(classdate)
from (
  -- your existing query
) x
group by userid, name, coursename, applicationtype
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should have two separate columns for what I think would be class start and end date (see Impaler's answer) because it makes it easier to do further analysis. If you don't mind seeing the same min and max classdate when there is only one classdate, you could simply do

```
select userid, name, coursename, applicationtype, concat(min(classdate),'-',max(classdate))
from t
group by userid, name, coursename, applicationtype
```